# Node.js and Telegraf TimeoutError: Promise timed out after 90000 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have a function that handles some pizza orders from a certain user. I divided it into two parts: getting data from the user and filling inputs, clicking buttons, etc.

```
const handleUserOrder = async (page, $, ctx) => {
    const {name, size, sauce} = await getUserOrder($, ctx)

    //absolutely unimportant and useless code for my issue goes below
}
```

The error appears in the first part of my function, i.e. getting data:

```
const getUserOrder = async ($, ctx) => {
    let titles = []
    $('.goods__list__title').slice(0, 30).each((index, element) => {
        const title = $(element).text().trim()
        titles.push(title)
    })
    await ctx.reply(`Ну ладно, держи список: \n\n${titles.map(title => title + ' (' + (titles.indexOf(title) + 1) + ')').join('\n')}`)
    await keyboard.sendMessage(ctx.from.id, 'Напиши номер той пиццы, которую ты выбрал.')

    const name = await getName(titles)
    await keyboard.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, `Значит ${name}. Размер?`)
    const size = await getSize(ctx)
    await keyboard.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, `Так, с размером определились. Может теперь выберешь соус?`)
    await keyboard.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, 'Одну секунду...')
    const {sauce, order} = await getSauce(ctx)
    await keyboard.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, `Вот твой заказ: ${order}.`)
    return {name, size, sauce}
}
```

As you can see, I've created three functions for each piece of data I need to collect. And this is the place where the error occurs.

```
const getName = async (titles) => {
    const options = await titles.map(title => `${titles.indexOf(title) + 1}`)
    await ctx.reply('Выбирай любую!', {
        reply_markup: {
            keyboard: new Array(titles.length).fill(0).map((e, i) => [{text: `${i + 1}`}]),
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            remove_keyboard: true,
        }
    })
    await bot.hears(options, async (ctx) => {
        return titles[parseInt(ctx.match[0]) - 1]
    })
}
```

I've recognized that I get this error only if the `return` method is situated on the last level of nesting. Otherwise, if I, for example, just give `name` some certain value, instead of choosing it as a user, it works absolutely fine, because there is no nesting at all.

Do you have any ideas on how can I fix it?

This is how my code looks with Promise (**@ggorlen**'s advice):

```
const getName = async (titles, ctx) => {
    const options = await titles.map(title => `${titles.indexOf(title) + 1}`)
    await ctx.reply('Выбирай любую!', {
        reply_markup: {
            keyboard: new Array(titles.length).fill(0).map((e, i) => [{text: `${i +1}`}]),
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            remove_keyboard: true,
        }
    })

    return new Promise(res => {
        bot.hears(options, ctx => {
            res(titles[parseInt(ctx.match[0]) - 1])
        })
    })
}
```

And now after a little time passes after the function called I get this error:

```
(node:20076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Promise timed out after 90000 milliseconds
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/mishashkarubski/WebstormProjects/pizza/node_modules/p-timeout/index.js:39:64)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:20076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 

This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection,
use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:20076) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.
In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Your `return titles[...]` doesn't return to the caller of `getName` like you think -- it returns to the `bot.hears` API which probably ignores the result. The `async` in the `bot.hears` callback is pointless. You'll need `return new Promise(res => bot.hears( ... res(titles[...])))` or find a promise-based API instead of a callback.

Comment: @ggorlen I've tried to return a Promise instead of ```return titles[...]``` but now I don't get any result when I try to make my bot hear what I've typed (```bot.hears``` API doesn't work at all)

Comment: Feel free to add/replace the code to your question

Comment: This looks OK to me at a glance -- I don't have telegram so I can't really test this, but I'd try adding some logs to see what's running.

Comment: @ggorlen if it looks ok... do you think it could be a problem with API itself?

Comment: If there is a runtime error, remember to [show that error in your post](/help/how-to-ask) and make sure to explain which lines in the stack trace map to which lines in the code you're showing. Also remember that your post is going to outlive your need for it: don't put `edit: ... ` in your post, update it so that it stays one post, so that future visitors who find your question (hopefully with answer) can easily tell if it's the same problem they're having. Edits in answers make sense. Edits in questions do not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well, the only runtime error I get is that ```Promise timed out after 90000 milliseconds``` but I believe it is normal in case of my ```Promise``` return because it is ```undefined``` and that's what my question is about

Comment: Don't tell me. [tell everyone by putting those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask). If you get an error, put the entire error + stack trace in there with code formatting. Remember that your post is not "for you", it's "for you, and everyone else in the future" so when you're asked for details, those details need to go in your post, and then you can reply with an "I've update the post with that information" comment. (If you only want an answer "for you", SO is 100% the wrong place to ask ;)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added an error message to my question. Maybe you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Your post has no "timeline", unlike answers (which might need edits based on changes in the relevant ecosystems over time), so don't update it with "edit: ....". Instead, update the post in a way that keeps it a coherent problem description, just with the previously missing information worked in so that it's now a more detailed post.

Comment: As for the error: it's telling you that after waiting for a response in a promise for 90 seconds, Node gave up. So, start debugging: throw some console.log statements between your many `await` and see which one is stalling, then investigate from there. (`await blah` is just alternate syntax for working with Promises, with `x = await y` being equivalent to `y.then(x => ...)`)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your answer! :) But I already know that problem is located in my ```getName(...)``` function and Node gave up trying to return the new Promise, that I declared. The only thing I do not understand is why Node cannot return this Promise (it's not a problem with bot API, the alternate version before refactoring without any functions and returns works well).

Comment: There are three awaits in `getName`, so: which one? And once you know which one: update your post again, because if you know where the problem is, show the code relevant to the problem, and only the code relevant to the problem. This is why you're advised to create a true [mcve]: not just for us, but also because _you_ running through that exercise almost always makes you find the problem on your own, removing any need to even post to SO. However, if you're still stuck after that, you now have good, focussed code to show in your post.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm talking about the last Promise that my function returns. ```options``` array exists, my console logs it. ```ctx.reply()``` also works because if it didn't work, I wouldn't see any message and markup in Telegram at all...

Comment: Right but notice what you're doing now: I'm telling you what to do, you tell me that you already did that... what do you need Stackoverflow for? You apparently know _exactly_ where things are going wrong, so the next steps are to check the documentation for that function, double check you're using it correctly, and if you are, ask the people who _make that library_ whether or not you're running into a bug. (you can of course still ask about that here, but right now your question doesn't seem focused on that function _at all_ so you'll want to radically rewrite your post to make it about that?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it like that?

```
const getName = async (titles) => {
    const options = await titles.map(title => `${titles.indexOf(title) + 1}`)
    
    await bot.hears(options, async (ctx) => {
await ctx.reply('Выбирай любую!', {
        reply_markup: {
            keyboard: new Array(titles.length).fill(0).map((e, i) => [{text: `${i + 1}`}]),
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            remove_keyboard: true,
        }
    })
        return titles[parseInt(ctx.match[0]) - 1]
    })
}
```